How to integrate Disputefox API with our application without zappier
I need to integrate disputefox API with my web application without using zappier. We can get the API key to integrate the disputefox with zapier. but I need to integrate Disputefox functions with my web application using javascript. I am using ReactJS for the front end. I tried to find the Disputefox API documentation and I couldn't find that. Is there anyone who can help me?
